# Multidimensional session array in PHP

Tags: php, session

I want to create a multidimensional session array in PHP.

```
$_SESSION['basket'][$id] = $array
```

`$array` refers to an array.

When I run this for a new `$id`, it is overwriting the previous entry in the `$_SESSION['basket']`.

Means every time `count($SESSION['basket'])` is `1`.

Actually, i want to achieve following structure.

`$_SESSION['basket'] = array($id1 => array(), $id2 => array(), .....)`

EDITED:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['basket'])) {                           
 $_SESSION['basket'] = array();
 $_SESSION['basket'][$id] = $array;
}
else{
 $_SESSION['basket'][$id] = $array;
}
```

when i do

```
$_SESSION['basket'][$id] = implode('/',$array);
```

it works. but not working for another array as value.

How can i do this?

thanks.

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: Did you first defined `$_SESSION['basket'] = array();` ?
And just then, $_SESSION['basket'][$id] = $array; etc.

Comment: then make sure that `$id` is unique so that it doesn't overwrite it

Comment: @Ghost: yes $id is unique. I am passing it in GET method.

Comment: Check `$id` value. Maybe it's null or something else

Comment: @u_mulder: I checked it. $id has the value which not unique and not same as previous

Comment: do u have `session_start()` in the top of your script as starters?

Comment: @DarkBee: yes . I can access all my other session variables. even if i store $array as string then it works but if i put $array as array then it starts overwriting.

Comment: Did you by chance pass the array you are trying to modify as a reference? (with `&$array`)

Comment: I did it... mistakenly, i was storing objects as value in $array. i cast it to string and it works...   thanks a lot

Comment: :) Thats why the value in the session will always reflect the value of `$array` because it's actually a pointer towards it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am providing the answer for my question. It may help some other people who have same issue.

do not store any objects in $_SESSION varibles. I was storing

```
$array = array( $key=>object($value),....)
```

Therefore, I cast object to string

```
$array = array($key => (string)$value, ...)
```

and it works.

hope it will help someone.

Comment: Please add info to your question that you are using objects for storing instead of arrays, mark your answer as the OPs Answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use it like this:

```
$tmp = $_SESSION['basket'];
$tmp[$id] = array();
$tmp[$id] = $array;
```

That'll work.

Comment: Defining can delete all keys stored in `$_SESSION['basket']` before. I doubt this decision.

Comment: if we define  " $_SESSION['basket'] = array() "   then it will always go in else statement. and also it will overwrite previous  " $_SESSION['basket'] = array() "..

Comment: @manoj: still it won't work. it keeps replacing previous value